# How to use Apache POI to convert a .XLS into a .HTML file?

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I'm trying to use the [example](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/ss/examples/html/) to convert a HSSFWorkbook into a .HTML file but the example isn't working because the Maven dependency I am using does NOT contain openxml4j  classes at all.  Why is this... there is no explanation anywhere?

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-beta2</version>
        </dependency>
```

And here is the code snippet from ToHtml.java that fails to locate classes:

```
 public static ToHtml create(InputStream in, Appendable output)
         throws IOException {
     try {
         Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(in);
         return create(wb, output);
     } catch ( InvalidFormatException e){
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot create workbook from stream", e);
     }
 }
```

Basically, the clases **WorkbookFactory** and **InvalidFormatException**  are not located.  How would I work around this?  I don't know where the equivilant factory would be in the standard POI that I am using.   Was there an undocumented deprecation or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full list of all the different components of POI, their dependencies and their Maven Artifact IDs are given in the [Apache POI Components page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components).

If you want to use both HSSF and XSSF (which the `WorkbookFactory` allows), you need to depend on `poi-ooxml` and not just `poi`.

Switch your maven dependency to `poi-ooxml` and it'll pull in all the required parts (including the straight `poi` jar), and your example code will then work

That said, you might also want to look at [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/), which provides support (built on POI and others) to turn a wide range of documents into HTML (+ detect types, get metadata etc)

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to avoid coding add a post-build step to my Jenkins job that converts my .XLS test outputs to .HTML using a bash shell script executing:  java -jar tika-app-1.4.jar --html $filename > $filename.html